# How to assign User to Breakout session with the zoom-andoid-sdk?

Tags: java, android, zoom-sdk

I want to automatically assign users to breakout-rooms during a meeting (not beforehand, not with CSV-import).

When I use the android-sdk demo app and add a listener, then the `IBOAdmin` is always  `null`.

```
ZoomSDKInitializeListener listener = new ZoomSDKInitializeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onZoomSDKInitializeResult(int errorCode, int internalErrorCode) {
        sdk.getInMeetingService().addListener(new InMeetingServiceAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onChatMessageReceived(InMeetingChatMessage inMeetingChatMessage) {
                IBOAdmin bOAdmin = sdk.getInMeetingService().getInMeetingBOController().getBOAdminHelper();

                // not working, bOAdmin is always null
                bOAdmin.assignNewUserToRunningBO("" + inMeetingChatMessage.getSenderUserId(), "Raum 1");
            }
        });
    }
    ...
};
sdk.initialize(context, listener, params);
```

The exceptions says:

```
Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean us.zoom.sdk.IBOAdmin.startBO()' on a null object reference
```

I tried to:

- Start the zoom conference from within the app (as `host`)
- Join an existing zoom conference and being assigned as `host`
- Join an existing zoom conference and being assigned as `co-host`
- Join an existing zoom conference with enabled breakout-session and being assigned as `co-host`

How can I assign other users to breakout-sessions with the Zoom Android SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

- Add the required app scopes
- Make sure, that the current user is allowed to manage breakout-session (is host or co-host)

To add the scopes:

1. Go to [zoom's marketplace development site](https://marketplace.zoom.us/develop)
2. At the dropdown on the top right choose "develop/build app"
3. At "SDK" choose "view here"
4. Go to the tab "Scopes"
5. Click on "+ Add scopes"
6. Choose the corresponding scopes (I just added all of them - just to be sure)